# How to pass list of RDDs to groupWith in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to pass a list of RDDs to groupWith instead of manually specifying them by index.

Here is the sample data

```
w = sc.parallelize([("1", 5), ("3", 6)])
x = sc.parallelize([("1", 1), ("3", 4)])
y = sc.parallelize([("2", 2), ("4", 3)])
z = sc.parallelize([("2", 42), ("4", 43), ("5", 12)])
```

Now I have created an array like this.

```
m = [w,x,y,z]
```

The manual hardcoded way is

```
[(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(m[0].groupWith(m[1],m[2],m[3]).collect()))]
```

which prints below result

```
[('1', ([5], [1], [], [])), 
('2', ([], [], [2], [42])), 
('3', ([6], [4], [], ])),
 ('4', ([], [], [3], [43])), 
('5', ([], [], [], [12]))]
```

But I would like to do something like pass `m[1:]` instead of passing manually.

```
[(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(m[0].groupWith(m[1:]).collect()))]
```

I tried to remove brackets but it has to be converted to string and i get below error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mapValues'

    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mapValues'
```

Comment: Try running `m[1:]`. It outputs 'ParallelCollectionRDD[27] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:423', not the actual name of the RDDs. Not sure how to solve your problem, but it at least explains with this code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `groupWith` accepts varargs all you have to do is to unpack arguments:

```
w.groupWith(*m[1:])
```

Comment: Great. that did the trick. thank you! Can't upvote without enough reputation.